# For non-normally distributed random variables, why does $[\mu - 1.96 \sigma, \mu + 1.96 \sigma]$ contain $\approx$ 95% of the distribution?

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, random-variable

My question is, if you take a random variable $X$ with an arbitrary distribution, which has a known and well defined mean & variance, then why does the following interval contain $\approx 95\% $ of the distribution?

$$
\left[\mu - 1.959 \times \sqrt{\sigma^2}, \quad  \mu + 1.959 \times \sqrt{\sigma^2}\right]
$$

Like I understand why this is true for normally distributed variables as $\pm
1.959$ is just the magic number that maps to the 2.5th and 97.5th percentile of the standard normal distribution, but why does this approximately still hold for non-normally distributed variables?

Some R-code examples:

```
##### Beta Distribution
a <- 3
b <- 40

# Formulas from wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution
mu <- a / (a+b)
sigma2 <-  a*b / (((a+b)^2) * ( a + b + 1))

bounds <- c(
    mu - 1.959 * sqrt(sigma2),
    mu + 1.959 * sqrt(sigma2)
)


pbeta(bounds[[2]], a , b) - pbeta(bounds[[1]], a , b) 
#> 0.9543413


##### Weibull Distribution
k <- 0.9
lambda <- 10

# Formulas from wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution
mu <- lambda * gamma(1 + 1/k)
sigma2 <- lambda^2 * (gamma(1 + 2/k) - gamma(1 + 1/k)^2) 

bounds <- c(
    mu - 1.959 * sqrt(sigma2),
    mu + 1.959 * sqrt(sigma2)
)

pweibull(bounds[[2]], k , lambda) - pweibull(bounds[[1]], k , lambda) 
#> 0.9484728
```

My guess is that this is just a property of the definition of the variance function itself however nothing obvious standards out to me as to why this holds, particularly on heavily skewed distributions.

Comment: Let's not confuse the issue of finding probability bounds for a distribution with the result from the central limit theorem, for which we can say that for most behaved distributions, the *sample mean* has an approximately normal distribution so that we can present $[\bar{X} - 1.96 \hat{S} / \sqrt{n},  \bar{X} + 1.96 \hat{S} / \sqrt{n}]$ as an interval estimate which contains 95% of *repeated samples of the mean under similar design*. Here I use

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is based on a false premise, and too many replies have been necessary to inform the OP of this.

Comment: @FrankHarrell - I'm not sure how best to resolve this question. I feel the way I phrased it in hindsight is unfortunate in it comes across as me making a statement which the answers below have shown to be false. In actuality what I was curious about is as to why/when the identity does seemingly hold true for many common distributions / transformations. I'm guessing at this point I would best served by marking one of the answers as correct (as by all-rights they have answered the question as it was written) and then opening a new question with a more refined scope?

Comment: *"In actuality what I was curious about is as to why/when the identity does seemingly hold true for many common distributions / transformations."* For which distribution other than the Gaussian distribution does this identify hold?

Comment: @Sextus It holds for many distributions -- you can construct them -- and it holds approximately for a huge number of distributions in practical applications.  Some people are surprised by this: the explanation is that there can be huge discrepancies in one tail that are compensated in the other tail.  *That* generality is the true strength of the 68-95-99.7 rule.

Comment: @whuber of course, there will be an infinite number of distribution for which it holds. But what are the many common distributions for which it holds? In response to the comment 'how to resolve this question', I would say that it is neccesary to at least provide a better support for the claimed statement.

Comment: @Sextus You could start with, say, Gamma distributions.  Provided the shape parameter is $1$ or greater, the error does not exceed 0.2%.  Or Beta distributions: provided both shape parameters are $2$ or greater, the error is usually less than 1% and never more than 2.81%.  I think this demonstrates the premise of the question is *not* false, as claimed elsewhere in these comments.

Comment: I appreciate the spirit in which the section labeled "EDIT" is offered, but this really changes the meaning of the question. I think the better alternative is to remove the EDIT and ask a new question that focuses on the more specific meaning that you have in mind. You can link to that question if you like.

Comment: @Sycorax - I was going back and forth on that for ages. I think in hindsight you are right. I will remove the edit and make a new question. Thanks for your input

Comment: @whuber 0.2% or 1% sounds like only a small difference when we compare it as 95.2% versus 95%, or 96% versus 95%. But comparing percentages can be deceptive. We can also consider it as 4.8% versus 5% or 4% versus 5%. Close to a hundred percent these small steps become relatively more important.

Comment: @Sextus That's an excellent point.  A better way to compare would be to subtract the logits.  But regardless, a $\pm0.2\%$ error at 95% is mighty good.  The basic idea is that those who would limit the 68-95-99.7 rule to the Normal distribution fail to appreciate (or exploit) its full usefulness.

Comment: @gowerc A small suggestion: when simulations leads you to a conjecture (*oh, it seems like X happens*), the next step is to use further simulation, or algebra, or other tools, to try as hard as you can to *disprove* your conjecture by searching for a counterexample or situations where the pattern no longer holds, rather than finding more confirming examples. Becoming successful at finding counterexamples is pretty demonstrably building some form of intuition.

Comment: @Glen_b - Thank you for your comments.  Doing many experiments following your advice what I am seeing so far is that, for continuous unimodal distributions, the proposed identity appears to hold true if the tails of the distribution are not "too diffuse" or "too concentrated".  The best definition I have of that so far is $ 1.1 < (sd(x) / sd(y)) < 1.5$ where $y$ = all of x within the 2.5th and 97.5th percentiles of x. At least I've not yet found any examples of continuous unimodal distributions that meet this criteria that don't meet the proposed identity.

Comment: I should add I am fully aware none of what I have said is formal or rigourous; I am just sharing my observation that the identity in the OP appears to always hold when the above condition holds.

Comment: The boundary cases for continuous unimodal distributions will be a uniform (100% of the distribution is within $\mu\pm\sqrt{3}\sigma$ - an actual strictly unimodal distribution can come as close to this as you wish) and  a symmetric mixture of two uniforms; it's possible to construct one that attains the $88.4\%$ figure within $\mu\pm 1.96\sigma$ that  I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unless the $\approx$ symbol is taken so broadly as to be almost meaningless, the premise of your question is false.

A few examples do not establish a general rule; they only establish that you didn't try cases that would get you far from what you found.

Clearly the proportion within 1.96 standard deviations cannot exceed 1 (since that's all the area there is), so presumably you don't intend it to extend as far from 0.95 as that.

But by [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality), it can be as low as $1-\frac{1}{k}^2$ where $k=1.95996...$ ($k=\Phi^{-1}(0.975)$), which is less than 75% (73.968%).

The bound is tight - the limiting case is a symmetric three-point distribution, with spikes at $\mu$ and $\mu\pm k\sigma$. We can construct a sequence of distributions that approach the limiting distribution (and the Chebyshev bound for the proportion) as closely as desired.

However, if you restrict consideration to [continuous unimodal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vysochanskij%E2%80%93Petunin_inequality),  then the lower bound is much closer. The proportion of the distribution within $\mu\pm 1.96\sigma$ would then be limited to be between about 88.4% and 100% and in that case there's considerably more scope for saying it's "about" 95%, but that's still fairly broad. If you want to bound it more closely still, so that $\approx$ in your title isn't doing quite such heavy lifting, you'd need further conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your response this broadly makes sense. Though sorry with regards to "would then be limited to be between about 88.4% and 100%" where does that lower limit of 88.4%" come from ?

Comment: I believe it's meant to be $1-1/9\approx 88.9\%$ as given by [Gauss's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_inequality).

Comment: Must admit, whilst I understand the argument for why the identity doesn't hold true generally, I still find it curious that for many continuous unimodal distributions it does. Testing many distributions and simple transformations it is remarkable to me how well it holds up in practice (again yes it is easy to construct examples where it doesn't). My stab in the dark guess would be that many distributions can be reasonably approximated by a normal distribution which is why the identity then holds.

Comment: It approximately holds for a number of fairly non-normal distributions, so I don't think "approximate normality" is necessarily a full explanation of what we see here. A full accounting would, however, require making some of the notions precise enough to assess the claim (like just how we're defining "approximate" each time the word is used)

Comment: @whuber Note that we're not talking about 2sd's but  about 1.96 sd's, so not 88.89%, but something very slightly different from that.

Comment: @whuber Gauss' inequality, being about the mode, would seem to require us to restrict consideration to the symmetric unimodal case but unless I've had a brain seizure there's a subsequent result (of the same form as Gauss but about the mean) that doesn't require symmetry. I'm trying to remember the correct reference.

Comment: This is it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vysochanskij%E2%80%93Petunin_inequality There's also DasGupta's (2000) inequality for normal mixtures (which is less general but still fairly broad), which I think would give a lower bound of 91.3% in this case

Comment: er, I should have said scale mixtures of normals, if I remember the DasGupta inequality right

Answer (score 8):

The claim is false for *arbitrary distributions* (unless $\approx$ is vacuously defined). We can show this using Chebyshev's inequality.

By Chebyshev's inequality, we know that given $0 < \sigma < \infty$, then $ \Pr(|X - \mu|\ge k\sigma)\le\frac{1}{k^2}$ for any $k>0.$

For the case of $k=1.96$, we have $ \Pr(|X - \mu|\ge 1.96\sigma)\le\frac{1}{1.96^2} = 0.260308 \dots$

So we know that there exists some distribution that has the property
$$
\begin{align}
\Pr(\mu - 1.96\sigma < X < \mu + 1.96\sigma) &\ge1 - 0.260308\dots  \\ 
&\ge0.739692 \dots  \\
&\not\approx 0.95
\end{align}$$

We can find an example where the equality is obtained.
$$
\begin{array}{r|c}
\text{event} & \text{probability} \\
\hline
1.96 & \frac{1}{2 \cdot 1.96^2} \\
0 & 1 - \frac{1}{1.96^2} \\
-1.96 & \frac{1}{2 \cdot 1.96^2}
\end{array}
$$
By inspection, all of the probabilities are non-negative and sum to 1, so we know that this is a probability distribution. Likewise, we can read off that the mean must be 0 (if you don't believe me, apply the definition of expectation).

Applying the definition of variance, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sigma^2 &= \frac{1}{2 \cdot 1.96^2}(0 - 1.96)^2 + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 1.96^2}(0 + 1.96)^2 + 0\\
&= 1
\end{align}$$

Plugging in to Chebyshev's inequality:
$$
\begin{align}
\Pr( - 1.96 < X <  1.96) &= 1 - \frac{1}{1.96^2} \\
&= 0.739692\dots \\
&\not\approx 0.95
\end{align}$$

We can generalize to an absolutely continuous distribution which comes arbitrarily close to the lower bound. One example is a mixture of three normal distributions with means at the zero and $\pm 1.96$, very small variances, and mixture coefficients given in the table.

Comment: For some counterpoint, and an explanation concerning why I find this analysis less than useful, note that the constraint on a distribution $F$ of the form $F[\mu+1.96\sigma]-F[\mu-1.96\sigma]=95/100$ defines a codimension-1 set in the space of all continuous finite-variance distributions, revealing such distributions as extremely numerous. Moreover, in the natural metric on that space, many commonly used distributions are close to one of these.  The constructive approach to addressing the question then (IMHO) is to *provide practical characterizations* of the neighborhood of that subspace.

Comment: @whuber These are interesting observations, but they address a question that wasn't asked. I had hoped that OP would ask a new question in this vein and that reflected your previous comments on their question and was a little more careful in ints phrasing, because that would indeed be more interesting.

Comment: Although the question wasn't *literally* asked, it was, in my reading, *specifically* what was intended by the use of "approximately equal" ("$\approx$") and "approximately still hold for non-normally distributed variables" in the statement.

Comment: What is the intended meaning of “arbitrary distribution”?

Comment: I stated my interpretation of "arbitrary distribution" in the first comment.  It can be enlarged to all distributions with finite variance provided you are a little careful in interpreting "95% of the" to account for the possibility of finite probabilities at the endpoints of the interval.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being thick, but if you replace "arbitrary distributions" with the distributions that have the property $F[\mu+1.96\sigma]-F[\mu-1.96\sigma]=95/100$, what is the question? If we're only considering distributions that have this property, what is actually being asked about?

Comment: Abstractly, we are given a parameter -- a scalar property -- of a distribution and are asked whether this property for non-Normally distributed variables is at least "approximately" (in some sense) close to its value for Normally distributed variables.  One constructive way to respond is to provide a relatively simple characterization of such distributions based on other familiar properties such as skewness, kurtosis, etc.,  (I studied this and found that the relationship between low-order moments and this particular property is complicated.)